# Change mongodb data directory ubuntu permission

Tags: linux, files, permissions, mongodb

I want to change my mongodb data directory to my external media. The problem is that when I change data dir to my media (other than home dir), it does not work, but it works for home dir:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-11-22 12:46:57 EST; 3s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 144014 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
   Main PID: 144014 (code=exited, status=100)

Nov 22 12:46:57 nimashiri-G5-5000 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Nov 22 12:46:57 nimashiri-G5-5000 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Nov 22 12:46:57 nimashiri-G5-5000 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the path used for the new data directory? I guess you are using a mounted media with no sufficient permissions or maybe this one is owned by root.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Exactly. I just solve the problem by using compiled binaries. Because in this case, I could define data directory from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I just used compiled binaries to achieve my goal. You may follow [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-tarball/).

Comment: It's not clear to me how "compiled binaries" solved the problem, and there's no mention of compiled binaries at the link you gave. Can you elaborate?